# What does obj_now_BVHtree.overlap(obj1,obj2) return?

Tags: python, bvh

I am using BVHtree.overlap in a script to calculate the overlap between 2 meshes. If there is no overlap this returns None. If there is an overlap a list is returned.
For example:

```
[(47491, 496), (47491, 498), (47310, 498), (47309, 498), (47036, 491), (47036, 498), (47581, 496), (47581, 489), (47580, 489), (47401, 496), (47035, 491), (47307, 489), (47216, 491), (47217, 491), (47032, 491), (47399, 489), (47308, 489), (46852, 491), (47031, 491), (47134, 489), (47134, 465), (46851, 491), (47030, 467), (47030, 465), (46934, 491), (46934, 467)]
```

What do the values in this list represent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`mathutils.bvhtree.BVHTree.overlap`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/mathutils.bvhtree.html#mathutils.bvhtree.BVHTree.overlap) returns a list of unique tuples, where each tuple represents the overlap between two elements of the two trees. The first entry of each tuple is the index from one tree and the second entry is from the other tree.

> **`overlap`**`(other_tree)`
>
> Find overlapping indices between 2 trees.
>
> - **Parameters**: **`other_tree`**[`(BVHTree)`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/mathutils.bvhtree.html#mathutils.bvhtree.BVHTree) – Other tree to perform overlap test on.
> - **Returns**: Returns a list of unique index pairs, the first index referencing this tree, the second referencing the other_tree.
> - **Return type**: `list`

Comment: Is it possible to retrieve XYZ coordinates of the overlap from this list of index pairs? I sorry if this is a stupid question. I am quite new to blender.

Comment: @Bram Sorry for my late reply. The indices are for the polygons that are intersecting. Describing an intersection through XYZ coordinates is not the right approach since that would only be the case if the two polygons touch at exactly one point, usually it would be a line of the two planes intersecting (or even more complex shapes with quads and ngons that are not planar).